# Apex rest service error: The requested resource does not exist

Tags: apex, apexrest

I am trying to build apex rest service which returns json/xml response . The api needs to support the below call

Sample Call:-

[API endpoint]/services.[format]

[API endpoint]/services/[service_code].[format]

Where format is json/xml

Here is my Issue when i call the service [API endpoint]/services it returns the correct result,but when i call the service

[API endpoint]/services.xml or [API endpoint]/services.json i get the below error

[{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}]

Can any one provide any pointers regarding the issue ?

Below is the apex rest service code:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/v2/services/*')
global with sharing class ServicesRestAPI_v2{

/*
    GET Service List / Get Service Definations

*/ 
@HttpGet
global static void getServices() {
     RestRequest req = RestContext.request; 
     RestResponse response = RestContext.response; 

     String format = req.requestURI.split('\\.').size()>1?req.requestURI.split('\\.')[1]:'';

     String responseStr;

     /*
      check to see whether jurisdiction_id is passed
     */
     String jId = req.params.get('jid');



     try{ 
         // see if a service code was  part of the URI
         String serviceCode= req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
         serviceCode = serviceCode.split('\\.').size()>1?serviceCode.split('\\.')[0]:serviceCode;          

         if (serviceCode!= '' && !serviceCode.startsWith('services')) {
              //we have the service code here  : this is always done only if metadat =true
              if(req.headers.get('Content-Type')==APIConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON || format=='json')  
                responseStr= ServicesAPIResponse.sendJSONResponse(ServicesHelper.getService(serviceCode),ServicesHelper.getServiceMetadata(serviceCode)); 
              else
                responseStr= ServicesAPIResponse.sendXMLResponse(ServicesHelper.getService(serviceCode),ServicesHelper.getServiceMetadata(serviceCode)); 
         } else {                
              if(req.headers.get('Content-Type')==APIConstants.CONTENT_TYPE_JSON || format=='json') 
                responseStr= ServicesAPIResponse.sendJSONResponse(ServicesHelper.listAllServices(jId)); 
              else
                responseStr= ServicesAPIResponse.sendXMLResponse(ServicesHelper.listAllServices(jId));                 
         } 

     }catch(CustomException e){             
            if(APIConstants.NOT_FOUND==e.getMessage()){
                response.statuscode =404;   
                responseStr= CustomException.sendJSONApiErrorResponse('Invalid service_code provided');            
            }               
     } 

     RestContext.response.responseBody =   Blob.valueOf(responseStr);  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a service that returns JSON for .json and XML for .xml or no extension.

I notice that your URL mapping is:

```
urlMapping='/v2/services/*'
```

which I assume will not match either of these (try them):

```
[API endpoint]/services.json
[API endpoint]/services.xml
```

but would match either of these:

```
[API endpoint]/services/[service_code].json
[API endpoint]/services/[service_code].xml
```

Perhaps you need to introduce a "none" or "unknown" dummy service code or use the rather ugly:

```
[API endpoint]/services/.json
[API endpoint]/services/.xml
```

**PS**

On the status code question, this is what I have done in a couple of places:

```
@HttpGet
global static void get() {
    RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
    if (res == null) {
        res = new RestResponse();
        RestContext.response = res;
    }
    try {
        res.statusCode = 200;
        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(readConfiguration());
    } catch (EndUserMessageException e) {
        res.statusCode = 400;
        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        res.statusCode = 500;
        res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf('SERVER ERROR\n\n' + String.valueOf(e) + '\n\n' + e.getStackTraceString());
    }
}
```

Comment: no that does not work either

Comment: @Sneha Strange. Your are including your "v2" in the path aren't you? I suggest you find a case that works and start from there.

Comment: yes i am adding v2 in the path. The problem started when i change the return type from String to void and added the response in this RestContext.response.responseBody =   Blob.valueOf(responseStr);

Comment: @Sneha In code where I set the `responseBody` I also set the `statusCode` to 200 when everything is OK and other values for errors.

Comment: Sorry did not understand..You mean should i add status code?

Comment: @Sneha See the "PS" I just added: yes I am explicitly setting the status code. May or may not help with your problem.

Comment: Not working..Have tried many options all of them seems to fail. Also sending String as return type does not help as it is encoded and when you do .xml format it add some extra tags in response..

Comment: @Sneha Sorry to hear that. All I can suggest is to start from scratch in a new class working as simply as possible and build up from there testing as you go.